# Skype Integration in native

Tags: ios, skype, skypedeveloper

I'm going to integrate `Skype` (objective c) in native iOS app . I referred this
  [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-ios-app-sdk-samples).

[image]

Not able to connect with the server. Meeting url I've changed in `info.plist` as [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/getmeetingurl) but is not working.

Comment: First link is broken.

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-ios-app-sdk-samples